# Passing Data to Template

Tags: django, django-models

I have following data I want to pass to Django Template.

```
______________________________________
|Server | Info Events | Error Events |
|_______|_____________|______________|
|servera|   30        |     12       |
|_______|_____________|______________|
|serverb|   5         |     22       |
|_______|_____________|______________|
|serverc|   10        |     18       |
|_______|_____________|______________|
|serverd|   20        |     02       |
|_______|_____________|______________|
|servere|   38        |     23       |
|_______|_____________|______________|
```

I want to pass this data over to template using

```
return render (request, 'serverdata':serverdata)
```

but I need help to know how can we do this for rows containing more than one column

if it contained only 1 column , I can store it as a Dictionary, but what in case of more than one columns of information ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. That is not valid syntax, to start with; but what is this data? Why is having multiple columns an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official documentation of [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) clarifies that:

> context
>
> A dictionary of values to add to the template context. By default, this is an empty dictionary. If a value in the dictionary is callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.

In other words, you must do the following:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render


def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
```